# Dom Nodes manipulations, how remove tags which wrap my selection?

Tags: jquery, dom, textnode

I try to explain you my "problem". I would like to know when I select a part of text, if this text is “wrapped” by html tags, and in function delete them.

For example with this sentence :

*The car is `<strong>`green`</strong>`, and the boat is black*

If I select “green” and click on a button, I would like verify if green is wrapped by `<strong>`(for that it’s ok), and in function delete `<strong>` tags without delete containing “green”.

I have tried to do it, but when I remove child and recreate one, my new node is empty and if I try to put directly text in `document.createTextNode`, my new node appears but the `<strong>` tags stay.

```
// Bouton CLICK
    $('input[type=button].btn_transform').click(function(){

var selObj = window.getSelection();    
        var parent=selObj.anchorNode.parentNode;

        if (parent.nodeName=='STRONG'){       
           parent.removeChild(selObj.anchorNode);
            var theText = document.createTextNode(selObj);
            parent.appendChild(theText);             
        }
    });
```

I’m not a DOM manipulation specialist. Could you help me to solve this?

Thanks very much for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post for a selection method which selects the information no matter which browser it is:

[Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

I think if you make use of SelectText method then it should work fine instead of getSelection()

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It should work how you want it by just setting the parent's outerHTML (`<strong>green</strong>`) to it's innerHTML (`green`), like this:

```
$('input[type=button].btn_transform').click(function(){ 

    var selObj = window.getSelection();     
    var parent=selObj.anchorNode.parentNode; 

    if (parent.nodeName=='STRONG'){        
        parent.outerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried but it doesn't function or I don't undestand well your solution..

Comment: It should just replace the content with the tag with just the content.  What happens when you run this code?

Comment: I would like keep the same content without tags.

ex : "the <strong>cat</strong> is black" to "the cat is black".

When I run your code on Firefox, I have nothing. No message, no error on Firebug.

Comment: Hmmm, I was testing in Chrome where it worked. The problem is that in Chrome the parent is the `strong` tag, but in Firefox it is the parent of all the text (a div in my testing), so it never enters the `if` block. This also won't work on IE at all (but can be fixed to). Does this need to be cross-browser (because that might be difficult)? I'll see if I can figure something out for Firefox if I have time later.

Answer (score 0):

using mostly jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_transform").click(function () {
            var selectedText = getSelText();
            var parentOf = $("strong:contains(" + selectedText + ")");
            $(parentOf).each(function () {
                if (this.tagName == "STRONG" || this.tagName == "strong") {
                    var theElement = $(this);
                    var itsText = $(this).text();
                    $(this).after(itsText);
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    function getSelText(){
       // your chosen 'get selection' method...
    {
```

The only problem you might have is if you select text that appears more than once - therefore the function will match all instances of this text being contained in between `<strong>` tags and delete them all.

Might give you some ideas though I guess.
Rob